# getting character from string and using it as array index... ASM

Tags: arrays, assembly, printf, character, nasm

Having trouble using a string array and getting each character from it and adding a 1 to a frequency table of the corresponding ascii index (frequency table is indexed by ascii value):  Example, get character 'a' then add 1 to the frequency table of index of the array ['a'].  I was getting segmentation errors and now getting error: invalid combination of opcode and operands, talking about `mov ax, al`
Any questions about the parameters of the problem please ask.  I have working on this for hours and could really use another pair of eyes to check what I am doing wrong (syntax/concept **if you see one**)  Please help.

Update: I have got it print stuff out, so I think it is "working"; however I am now trying to print the characters that each array index corresponds.  It won't print the character of the array that I am pointing to (it prints literally nothing for the character).

**Latest update:  I got it to work.  changed some of the code under the label .loopa and now it works fine! :)**
Code below:

```
SECTION .data               ; Data section, initialized variables
 array5:     db "Hello, world...", 0
 array5Len:  equ $-array5-1
 asoutput:   db "%s", 0        ; string output
 newline:    db "", 10, 0      ; format for a new line
 acoutput: db "%c: ", 0                 ; output format for character output

SECTION .bss                   ; BSS, uninitialized variables
 arrayq:     resd 128          ; frequency array of the first 127 ascii values initialized to 0 (none have been counted yet)

SECTION .text
  global main           ; the standard gcc entry point
  main:                 ; the program label for the entry point
    push    ebp         ; set up stack frame
    mov     ebp,esp

    mov esi, array5
    mov edi, 0
    mov ebx, arrayq
    mov ecx, array5Len
; get each character of array5 and add 1 to the frequency table of the corresponding ascii value (which the arrayq is indexed by ascii value).
.loopf:
    xor eax, eax
    mov al, [esi]
    ;mov ax, [esi]
    ;mov ax, al
    ;mov cx, ax
    add edi, eax
    mov ebx, 1
    add [arrayq+4*edi], ebx

    mov edi, 0
    add esi, 1
    loop .loopf

    push dword array2
    push dword asoutput
    call printf
    add esp, 8

    push dword newline
    call printf
    add esp, 4

    ;pop ebx    
    mov ebx, arrayq
    mov ecx, 128                            ; size of arrayq
    mov esi, 0                              ;start at beginning
.loopa:
    mov eax, 0
    cmp [ebx+esi], eax
    je .skip
    mov eax, esi
    push ebx
    push ecx
    mov ebx, 4
    cdq
    div ebx
    push eax
    push dword acoutput
    call printf
    add esp, 8
    pop ecx
    pop ebx

    push ebx
    push ecx                                    ; make sure to put ecx (counter) on stack so we don't lose it when calling printf)
    push dword [ebx + esi]                  ; put the value of the array at this (esi) index on the stack to be used by printf
    push dword aoutput                          ; put the array output format on the stack for printf to use
    call printf                                 ; call the printf command
    add esp, 8                                  ; add 4 bytes * 2
    pop ecx                                     ; get ecx back
    pop ebx

    push ebx
    push ecx
    push dword newline
    call printf
    add esp, 4
    pop ecx
    pop ebx

.skip:
    add esi, 4
    loop .loopa
.end:
    mov     esp, ebp    ; takedown stack frame
    pop     ebp         ; same as "leave" op
```

Comment: `mov ax, al` doesn't work because you are asking to move an 8-bit value to a 16-bit register. However that move would be pointless anyway because `al`, `ax`, and `eax` are all the same register, just the lower 8 bits, the lower 16 bits, and the full 32 bits of it, respectively. So after your `mov al, [esi]` you can use the `eax` value immediately for indexing into your frequency table.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError thanks that solved that part of the program, now I have a "slightly" different issue...

Comment: Maybe I do not understand your code, but wouldn't it be the easiest way to get the char and use it as the index for your ascii-count-array arrayq  like this: `add [arrayq + 4*eax], dword 1`?
Hm, you need to initialise your ascii count arraayq with zeros first, or?  A loop with: `mov ecx, 128`, `mov [arrayq + 4 * ecx], dword 0`

Comment: @Blechdose the program must have an frequency array of ascii values with all the values initialized to zero to start :/

Comment: @Rex Since *arrayq* is in the *.BSS* section you need to explicitly zero it's content. Your code up to now does not do that.

Comment: @user3144770 anything in the .BSS is automatically zeroed out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed code under .loopa label to make it print the character the index is corresponding to:

```
    .loopa:
    mov eax, 0
    cmp [ebx+esi], eax
    je .skip
    mov eax, esi
    push ebx
    push ecx
    mov ebx, 4
    cdq
    div ebx
    push eax
    push dword acoutput
    call printf
    add esp, 8
    pop ecx
    pop ebx
```

Comment: What is the purpose of this division by 4 if the intent is to output a character?

Comment: Because I want to output a character not a integer value, which is what is stored in the frequency array.

Comment: A closer look reveals the division is indeed needed but then at least simplify the code and write `mov eax,esi` and `shr eax,2`.